# Django single DB connection

Tags: python, django, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm have a Django micro-service, that constantly runs a lot of tasks in the background (using a few child processes that run multiple threads), regardless of the request-response flow.

Since every thread uses the ORM constantly, at some point I get an error for "too many clients" connected to the DB, and after that happens, it persists even after restarting the worker that got the exception.
This is weird, since the app never spawns more than around 30-40 threads in parallel, and the PostgreSQL DB supports 100, but I guess every thread makes Django create a few connections of something like that...

I've tried using `db.connection.close()` at the end of each thread, but it seems to have no effect.

Is there any way to make Django use a **single** connection cursor for each process? Why does it even create new connections for each thread/query/whatever?

**NOTE:**
I am **not** sharing the connection between the worker processes. Before spawning the child processes, I used `db.connections.close_all()`

Comment: Django uses a single connection per thread. Sharing a connection between threads would break the semantics of Django's transaction management. If you want to share it, you'll need to explicitly share the psycopg2 connection object itself. If you frequently spawn new threads, the resources used by the old connection might not be freed fast enough. You could try connection pooling, using e.g. [PgBouncer](https://pgbouncer.github.io/).

Comment: I had the same problem. I created threads in loop. After I created threads on loop iteration, I waited for their terminations with .join() method. When all threads terminated, I called db.connections.close_all() from main thread. That worked for me.